# How to highlight a button as the next logical action, in wxpython

Tags: wxpython

Dialogs in a lot of programs have one button highlighted to suggest a logical next move. On my Mac, it's usually pulsing blue.

How do I do that in wxpython?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to set the focus yourself:

```
MyButton.SetFocus()
```

Then the button will be in focus. If that's not what you're talking about, then it might require something custom.